# Why does shared_ptr use placement new

Tags: c++, c++11

I've read at many places that when using `make_shared<T>` to create a `shared_ptr<T>`, its control block contains a block of storage large enough to hold a `T`, and then the object is constructed inside the storage with placement new. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct shared_ptr_control_block {
    std::atomic<long> count;
    std::atomic<long> weak_count;
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof (T), alignof (T)> storage;
};
```

But I'm a bit confused why we can't just have a member variable with type `T` instead? Why create the raw storage then use placement new? Can't it be combined in one step with a normal object of type `T`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's to allow lifetime management.

The control block is not destroyed until `weak_count` is zero.  The `storage` object is destroyed as soon as `count` reaches zero.  That means you need to directly call the destructor of `storage` when the count reaches zero, and *not* in the destructor of the control block.

To prevent the destructor of the control block calling the destructor of `storage`, the actual type of `storage` cannot be `T`.

If we only had the strong reference count, then a `T` would be fine (and much simpler).

---

In actual fact, the implementation is a bit more complex than this.  Remember that a shared_ptr can be constructed by allocating a `T` with `new`, and then constructing the `shared_ptr` from that.  Thus the *actual* control block looks more like:

```
template<typename T>
struct shared_ptr_control_block {
    std::atomic<long> count;
    std::atomic<long> weak_count;
    T* ptr;
};
```

and what `make_shared` allocates is:

```
template<typename T>
struct both {
    shared_ptr_control_block cb;
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof (T), alignof (T)> storage;
};
```

And `cb.p` is set to the address of `storage`.  Allocating the `both` structure in `make_shared` means that we get a single memory allocation, rather than two (and memory allocations are expensive).

Note:  I have simplified: There has to be a way for the shared_ptr destructor to know whether the control block is part of `both` (in which case the memory cannot be released until done), or not (in which case it can be freed earlier).  This could be a simple bool flag (in which case the control block is bigger), or by using some spare bits in a pointer (which is not portable - but the standard library implementation doesn't have to be portable).  The implementation can be even *more* complex to avoid storing the pointer *at all* in the `make_shared` case.

Comment: Ah, I see now. So if we had only one reference count (the strong count), then a `T` would be enough, right?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that make_shared combines the control block and the object in order to reduce the number of memory allocations required. simply constructing a shared_ptr required one allocation for the object being shared and one allocation for the control block.

Comment: Don't forget to account for a custom deleter you can set for T*, with that you can differentiate between in place storage and external pointer by storing a function pointer to the in place destructor or `delete`.

Comment: Implementations also have to respect a custom deleter, which most likely is also stored in the control_block.

Comment: @WorldSEnder : Yes indeed - I was trying to avoid giving a tutorial on how a typical library will implement `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 7):

As weak pointers may outlive the stored object, the lifetime of the control block may have to exceed the lifetime of the stored object. If the managed object would be a member variable it could only get destroyed when the control block gets destroyed (or the destructor would be called two times).

The fact that the storage stays allocated even after the object itself is destructed can actually be a disadvantage of `make_shared` in memory constraint systems (although I don't know if this is something encountered in practice).